# How to install Python libpcap module on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, pcap, libpcap, sniffer

I started to work on a python sniffer project. I want to use the pcap module but my computer always says "No module named pcap". I read that libpcap and pcap come with OS X but actually, it doesn't work...

I made a lot of research on the web and still unable tu run my python code. How am I supposed to do for running / linking or installing pcap ?

Note that I recently update to OSX Yosemite (but I didn't know if pcap worked before).

Comment: `pip install pcap` or `easy_install pcap`

Comment: easy_install : `No local packages or download links found for pcap
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pcap')`

Comment: pip : `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pcap
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pcap to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pcap`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Install brew from [here](http://brew.sh/index_fr.html)
2. Run `brew doctor` from terminal
3. Solve the warnings from `brew doctor` results
4. Run `sudo easy_install pyrex`
5. Run `sudo easy_install pypcap`

=> This solved my problem (don't really know if brew is necessary)

Comment: Worked for me too, I was doing this: https://github.com/hortinstein/node-dash-button

Comment: worth noting that brew's version of libpcap is 1.9 whereas the org seems to be on 4.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I think the *library* libpcap exists on OS X, but you are looking for a python module to which wraps it. I think the one you want is actually called [pypcap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap), although I have no idea if that's the right/best one(*).  You should be able to install it with either

```
easy_install pypcap
```

or

```
pip install pypcap
```

depending on the details of your python installation. (You also need to make sure that `pip` and/or `easy_install` are installing in a place known to the python installation that you're using; this may depend on which python it is -- Apple's, python.org, brew, etc. -- and how you've set it up.)

(*) I don't even know what pcap does, so note that there are a lot of pcap-related modules listed on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pcap&submit=search).

Comment: I installed pypcap but the import line still return an error `No module named pcap`. Actually, what I want to do is just find the easiest way to sniff a TCP packet (with IP and port filtering), then extract the data that I'm interested in from the TCP payload... Notice that `import pypcap`doesn't work too.